# How to overlay Segoe MDL2 Assets glyphs for use in WPF TreeViewItem.Header?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, overlay

I just read about overlaying glyphs. I am trying it out.
This is the simplified xaml portion to compose the TreeViewItem.Header

```
<TreeViewItem.Header>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Name="icon" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
       Text="&#xED0D;" Foreground="Blue" Background="cyan" />
    <TextBlock Name="title"/>
  </StackPanel>
</TreeViewItem.Header>
```

It produces a header containing glyph ED0D like this:
[image]

However, I would like to overlay ED0C
[image]
onto glyph ED0D.

What avenues are available to me to perform such overlay to be used in the TreeViewItem.Header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put two TextBlocks on top of each other:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xED0C;" Foreground="Cyan"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xED0D;" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </Grid>

   <TextBlock x:Name="title"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]